# Trying to select copy paste table in Benzinga webpage , but i only get small part of selection

Tags: http, web-scraping

I am trying select copy paste the data from the table in the webpsge https://www.benzinga.com/analyst-stock-ratings I do this by scrolling to the bottom of the table and then select all the rows going upwards to the top. In the past I got the entire table whick could be up to 1000 rows. After copy and pasting to excel I get the 1000 rows.   I now only successfully paste only about 40 even when all rows were selected.  Any suggestions on how via select copy paste to get entire table? I'm not interested in selenium.

Answer (score 0):

This is a dynamic rendering page that only display some rows when scrolling. You could extract all rows from information in script part if you don't want to use selenium:

[image]